# Using different instance of self as argument to method in python

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a method that takes self and another instance of the same method as its arguments, for example:

```py
class AClass():
     
    def __init__(self, v:int)->None:
        self.var = v

    def a_method(self, other: AClass)->None:
        self.var = other.var
```

using the type hint `other: AClass` isn't recognised, and as such, the .var of `other.var` isn't highlighted in my IDE. My plan currently is to just remove the type hint, is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Your code may work as posted in python3.10. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is to use itself as an annotation inside the class, it can't be completely parsed. The correct way is to use the string:

```
def a_method(self, other: 'AClass') -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: Amazing, this worked as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is not working because `AClass` is not yet fully evaluated when you use it as type hint in one of its method. So at that time the `AClass` identifier is not yet available.

That is discussed at length in PEP563: https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

So you have 2 solutions:

- as already mentioned by @Mechanic Pig: turn the annotation into a string:

  `def a_method(self, other: 'AClass') -> None:`

  Note that tools that use type hint (such as `mypy` or doc generators) will 'convert back' that string into the appropriate type when they run.
- or enable Postponed Evaluation of Annotations by adding this line at the beginning of the file:

  ```
  from __future__ import annotations

  class AClass:
      def a_method(self, other: AClass) -> None:
          ...
  ```

  As the name suggests, when you enable Postponed Annotation Evaluation, the type annotations are ignored at first, then evaluated only after the whole file has been evaluated, so the `AClass` identifier is available at that time.